# Error After Installing Oibaf's Drivers on Yakkety Yak

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics

2 Hours ago I Installed Oibaf's graphics drivers and then i restarted, and from that point whenever i boot into ubuntu i get stuck on

```
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 234417/30295728 files, 5171544/120946688 blocks
```

and gets stuck on that blinking `_`.

I will guess most of you will tell me to uninstall the drivers but i don't want because of gallium nine's native DX9 support, a solution or an alternative would be much appreciated.

Just in case, here are the specs:

- 4GB of DDR3 Ram
- Intel Core I5 4200u
- AMD Radeon HD 8670m 1GB of VRAM
- Screen Res: 1366x768
- Intel HD Graphics 4400
- Ubuntu 16.10 Yakkety Yak

Comment: AFAIK, `amdgpu` is the only AMD graphics driver that works with 16.04

Comment: i don't want because of gallium nine's native DX9 support, a solution or an alternative would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a Duplicate!

Comment: @darkubuntuwithnutella: could you please elaborate why you think it's not duplicate of the linked question?

Answer (score 0):

It's a video driver problem. In Cinnamon, it will force the system to use Cinnamon safe mode. In `xfce`, `vlc` or any other video players, it won't start. We currently have to wait for a patch.